# custom view button click it's not working

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code.

i registered the button action by defining the view in xib.
btn is connected to dismissButtonClick but It didn't work when I clicked the button.
So I tried a way to override touchesBegan Func and It didnt' work.

My third attempt was gesture registration.
It also didn't work....

There is no way for me anymore.

plz help me guys.

```
@objc public class CustomView : UIView  {
    static let xibName = "xibName"

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton?
    var completion: (() -> Void)?

    var parentView : UIViewController!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public static func getInstance(_ vc : UIViewController, _ completion : (() -> Void)? ) -> UIView {

        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(CustomView.xibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomView

        view.parentView = vc
        view.completion = completion

        view.initUI()

        return view
    }

    func initUI() {

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(CustomView.dismiss))
        mainView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        btn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomView.dismiss), for: .touchUpInside)


        parentView.view.addSubview(self)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewTopAnchor?.constant = -150
        viewTopAnchor?.isActive = true

        setNeedsDisplay()
        layoutIfNeeded()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 ) {
            self.mainView.isHidden = false
            self.showAnimation()
        }
}


    //top down anim
    private func showAnimation(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() ) {
            self.viewTopAnchor?.constant = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    self.dismissAnimation(self.duration)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private func dismissAnimation(_ duration : Double){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration - 0.5) {

            self.viewTopAnchor?.constant = -150
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    self.completion?()
                    self.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touchBegan") // not called
        let touch = touches.first
    }

    public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touchBegan") // not called
        self.completion?()
        self.btn?.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @objc
    func dismiss(){
        print("dismiss") // not called
        self.completion?()
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    @IBAction func dismissButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        print("dismissButtonClick") // not called
        self.completion?()
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

---

```
CustomView.getInstance(view, completion)
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check your views' hierarchy in Xib and make sure your button is at the top of all the views.

Comment: @shraddha11 yes button is at the top of all the view...

Comment: Ok. Can you please show or explain how you connected button to Action? Which event you used for connect?

Comment: @shraddha11  Thanks for your help! I edited the post.

Comment: @Sean do you use NavigationBar?

Comment: @masoud don't use navigationbar

Answer (score 0):

```
    I have created one custom view with one button and wrote method which is called on button click. Please check it out it might be helpful in your case.

https://github.com/bhoomik/Custom_View_Demo 

    Custom View Code


    //
    //  CustomView.swift
    //  Temp
    //
    //  Created by Jaimin Modi on 19/02/20.
    //  Copyright © 2020 Jaimin Modi. All rights reserved.
    //

        import UIKit

    //
//  CustomView.swift
//  Temp
//
//

import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {


    static let xibName = "CustomView"

    @IBOutlet weak var viewTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton?
    var completion: (() -> Void)?

    var parentView : UIViewController!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public static func getInstance(_ vc : UIViewController, _ completion : (() -> Void)? ) -> UIView {

        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(CustomView.xibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomView
        view.parentView = vc
        view.completion = completion
       // view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 120)
        view.initUI()

        return view
    }


    func initUI() {

      //  let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(CustomView.dismiss))
       // mainView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        //btn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomView.dismiss), for: .touchUpInside)


        parentView.view.addSubview(self)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       // self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
      //  self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
     //   viewTopAnchor?.constant = -150

     //   viewTopAnchor?.constant = 300
      //  viewTopAnchor?.isActive = true



        let guide = self.parentView.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.parentView.view.leftAnchor),
             self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
             self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.parentView.view.rightAnchor),
             // segmentedControl!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80)]
                self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: 0)]


        )

        setNeedsDisplay()
        layoutIfNeeded()

       /* DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 ) {
            self.mainView.isHidden = false
            self.showAnimation()
        }*/

    }

    @IBAction func dismissButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        print("dismissButtonClick") // not called
       // self.completion?()
       // self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}

    UIView Controller code
    :


        import UIKit


        extension UIView {
            class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
                return Bundle(for: T.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
            }
        }

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var viewNav :  CustomView!

    var completion: (() -> Void)?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        /*viewNav  = UIView.fromNib()
        viewNav.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: viewNav.frame.size.height)

        self.view.addSubview(viewNav)*/


        CustomView.getInstance(self, completion)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

  [1]: https://github.com/bhoomik/Custom_View_Demo
```

Comment: @Sean i have tried to modify my code as per my code. But i was not getting any view in parent as per constraint given by you as i dont have complete code. So, i changed constraint. Please check might be helpful to you